# Python: Is there a pandas function to detect persons Online login status and assign identification numbers to them based on the login status?

Tags: python, pandas, authentication

I have this pandas dataframe, I am trying to assign status identification numbers at Status column to each user depending whether the LAST_ACCESSED column for the user (AD_USER_NAME) is [Offline, = 0, Available/Online = 1, Away = 2]
[Table before][1]
So that the resulting table will be like this
[Table After][2]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3I5BA.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXuTJ.png
I tried to use this code for the 'If function' loop but it didn't work

```
def flag(df1):
    
    if (df1['LAST_ACCESSED'] = df1['None'] and df1['LAST_ACCESSED'] = 0]):
        return 0
    elif (df1['LAST_ACCESSED'] > 0 and (df1['LAST_ACCESSED'] = df1['Run_date_Time']):
        return 1
    elif (df1['LAST_ACCESSED'] > 5 and df1['LAST_ACCESSED'] < df1['Run_date_Time']):
        return 2

df1['Status'] = df1.apply(flag, axis = 1)
```

Comment: Can you add Sample Data?

Comment: `(df1['LAST_ACCESSED'] = df1['None']` **-->** `(df1['LAST_ACCESSED'] == df1['None']`

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) … [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

Make a boolean array for each condition then use them when assigning values. Use `&` instead of `and`.  Use `==` for comparison, `=` is used for assignments.

```
zero_mask = (df1['LAST_ACCESSED'] == 0) & (df1['LAST_ACCESSED'] == df1['None'])
one_mask = (df1['LAST_ACCESSED'] > 0) & (df1['LAST_ACCESSED'] == df1['Run_date_Time'])
two_mask = (df1['LAST_ACCESSED'] > 5) & (df1['LAST_ACCESSED'] < df1['Run_date_Time'])

df1.loc[zero_mask,'Status'] = 0
df1.loc[one_mask,'Status'] = 1
df1.loc[two_mask,'Status'] = 2
```